# find fields in array not existant in column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have an array of ISO-codes ("DE", "AF"...) and a table 'country' with an ISO-column.

Now i need to filter all the codes from my array that are not existant in the ISO-column. In my mind that would look something like the following pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_array WHERE ("DE", "AF", ...) AS my_array NOT IN country.iso
```

Is there any way to do this in plain SQL besides of looping through the array in PHP (or generally any code)?

Comment: "array" is not a MySQL construct, so your question is unclear.

Comment: in this case it is a PHP array, although it would be sufficient to write a comma-seperated list directly to SQL

Answer (score 1):

it seem you need `not in`

```
select * from tbale where country.iso  in ('DE','AF')
```

Comment: that would give me all the unmatched values from the database column, not the values from the array...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `NOT IN`?  The correct syntax is:

```
WHERE country.iso NOT IN ('DE', 'AF', ...)
```

Comment: that would give me all the unmatched values from the database column, not the values from the array...